# FFMPEG Splitting MP4 with Same Quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I have one large MP4 file.  I am attempting to split it into smaller files.

```
ffmpeg -i largefile.mp4 -sameq -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:50:00 smallfile.mp4
```

I thought using -sameq would keep the same quality settings.  However, I must not understand what that does.

I'm looking to keep the same quality (audio/video) and compression with the split files.  However, this setting makes the split files much larger.

What flag(s) do I need to set to keep the same quality and attributes in the split files while maintaining the same quality to size ratio?

For instance if my original file is about 12 GB and is 1920x1080 with a bitrate of 10617kbps and a framerate of 23 frames/sec and 6 channel audio with 317kbps, I would like the split files to be the same only a third of this size (if i split it into three pieces).

Comment: FYI for anyone reading this: Don't use [`-sameq`, it doesn't mean "same quality"](https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#Why-was-the-ffmpeg-_002dsameq-option-removed_003f-What-to-use-instead_003f).

Answer (score 129, accepted):

If you want to just split the video without re-encoding it, use the `copy` codec for audio and video. Try this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:50:00 -i largefile.mp4 -acodec copy \
-vcodec copy smallfile.mp4
```

Note that this only creates the first split. The next one can be done with a command starting with `ffmpeg -ss 00:50:00`.

This can be done with a single command:

```
ffmpeg -i largefile.mp4 -t 00:50:00 -c copy smallfile1.mp4 \
-ss 00:50:00 -c copy smallfile2.mp4
```

This will create `smallfile1.mp4`, ending at 50 minutes into the video of `largefile.mp4`, and `smallfile2.mp4`, starting at 50 minutes in and ending at the end of `largefile.mp4`.

Comment: Using this method on an mp4 file, I get the first two seconds of every created file as a frozen frame (the audio plays normally). Any known reason for this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Update to latest ffmpeg.

Comment: @Robert I've updated many times since 2010. Thanks.

Comment: @RonHarlev This is the currently expected behavior. Without re-encoding, you can only cut videos at "key frames". Frames in between key frames don't carry enough information on their own to build a complete image. See:  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Seekingwhiledoingacodeccopy

Comment: thumb up for the `copy` argument. After applied it the time is reduced from 2 mins to under 5 seconds~!

Comment: Hi All - I realise this question is now very old, but I found it while looking for a solution to extracting a section from a video, avoiding the blank video with sound issue mentioned above, so figured this might help others who come here too:

I ended up running a command first to find all the KeyFrame points, then used those exact times to extract the video section I wanted.  I can't seem to post an actual reply, and only a little comment like this, so will post in two parts.

Comment: Find the KeyFrames:

ffprobe -select_streams v -skip_frame nokey -show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time,pict_type /PathTo/SourceVideoFilename

Extract a 60 second from 1 min in to 2 mins in (the times are from the output to the above command - all in seconds):

ffmpeg -i inputfilename -ss 60.345678 -to 120.123456 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -scodec copy outputfilename

Hope that helps someone else.

Alan.

Comment: Sorry for the crappy formatting - I can't seem to work out how to format well in these little comment boxes.

Comment: @Ron Harlev: This occurs only when *-i* parameter is given after *-ss* parameter. *-i* parameter must be given first.

Answer (score 17):

An **Alternate** way of doing it is:

Create a 2-min clip, starting after 10 minutes:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:10:00 -to 00:12:00 -c copy output.mp4
```

- `-i`  input file
- `-ss` start time in seconds or in hh:mm:ss
- `-to` end time in seconds or in hh:mm:ss
- `-c` codec to use

The quality of the file stays the same because we use `-c copy` to copy the original audio + video streams to the output.

**Reference, List of commonly used FFmpeg commands: [DigitalFortress](https://digitalfortress.tech/tricks/encode-videos-with-ffmpeg/)**

Comment: This post work perfectly because -i parameter is first parameter. Putting -ss parameter before - i parameter generate frozen/slow video when ss value is distinct from a start of frame.

Answer (score 2):

This is not bad, but not 100% right, it creates a 2-min clip, starting after 10 minutes, but it will only copy the best steams, so it will only copy the best video, audio and subtitle stream:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:10:00 -to 00:12:00 -c copy output.mp4
```

If you want to copy all streams, then add "-map 0", it basically selects the entire first input file:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:10:00 -to 00:12:00 -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy output.mp4
```

You also should put -ss and -to before the input file.