# splitting mp4 with ffmpeg does not remove chapters

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I created a bunch of mp4 videos from DVD images using handbrake. I need to split them, and this appears to work with the solution from this question [FFMPEG Splitting MP4 with Same Quality](https://superuser.com/questions/140899/ffmpeg-splitting-mp4-with-same-quality). For instance, to create the first split, I do:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:49:17 -i VideoTs-1.m4v -acodec copy -vcodec copy VideoTs-1_1.m4v
```

However, after the splitting, when I open the new file, it still has the original duration (01:37:29), and the chapters from the second half are still there, without the video stream. Looks like this in VLC:

[image]

How can I also remove the chapters and get a clean split at the specified time mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-map_metadata -1` to your command. This should strip the metadata like the chapter list.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.